# Split JSON data when comma is found

Tags: json

I want to separate and put `data` into array. Here's my AJAX code if it succeeded.

```
success : function(data){
                alert (data);
                $('#status').append("<p>Tax Declaration: "+data[0]
                                    + "<br/>Barangay: "+data[1]+"</p>"
                );
            },
```

sample out put is `08-09-0001-00047,BILAY`. I want them to be separated.

Comment: how about `data.split(",")`

Comment: Try reading the documentation for String.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string that is comma separated and you want to create an array of the items in the list, use [`split()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) like this:

```
var values = data.split(",");
$('#status').append(
    "<p>Tax Declaration: "+values[0] + "<br/>Barangay: "+values[1]+"</p>"
);
```

Comment: returns an error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 192.168.1.135/:3216`

Comment: Split works on strings. That error means `data` is not a string type. What is data?

Comment: Ahh..that's why! It's a list from my view.py `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list(m)),content_type='application/json')`. I am using Django framework.

Answer (score 0):

As @Andy Jones mentioned, use `.split()` like so:

```
success : function(data){
            data = data.split(/\s*,\s*/g);
            $('#status').append("<p>Tax Declaration: "+data[0]
                                + "<br/>Barangay: "+data[1]+"</p>"
            );
        },
```

Comment: returns an error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function